# How do you use tkinter entry boxes to make a variable?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm currently trying to create an "orbit simulator" and this part of the code is part of it. However an errors occur when I try to run it. The get() function seems to not work as it simply outputs that it doesn't exist.
I'm really stumped at this.

```
import tkinter
runwin = tkinter.Tk()
runwin.title("Orbit Sim")
runwin.geometry("320x320")
def run21():
    dt=ent21.get("1.0")
    tg=ent22.get("1.0")
    xz=ent23.get("1.0")
    yz=ent24.get("1.0")
    velz=ent25.get("1.0")
    runwin.destroy()
lbl21 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="How long to simulate for?").pack()
ent21 = tkinter.Entry(runwin).pack()
lbl22 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="How many seconds pass per check?").pack()
ent22 = tkinter.Entry(runwin).pack()
lbl23 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="Starting Positon? Please state X then Y.").pack()
ent23 = tkinter.Entry(runwin).pack()
ent24 = tkinter.Entry(runwin).pack()
lbl24 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="Starting Velocity").pack()
ent25 = tkinter.Entry(runwin).pack()
btn21 = tkinter.Button(runwin, text="Submit", command=run21).pack()
runwin.mainloop()
t=0
while t < dt:
    r3, t =m.sqrt((xz*xz)+(yz*yz)), t+tg
```

P.S. I'm not a genius at coding and the way i've written this code is pretty much the only way I can understand it without sufficient notes.

Comment: what error occurred?

Comment: Well the code after `mainloop()` wont run until you close the tkinter app. So that can be a problem as well.

Comment: @dbaker. Please make sure to vote and accept an answer. That is part of how other members can find what solved your problem if they are having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 problems I can see.

1st problem is you are using the grid manager on the widget directly and this will cause your get() method to error out. That is be cause the grid manager is returning `None`.
We can fix this by calling the grid manager on a new line.

2nd you are putting `"1.0"` in the get method and this is going to error out.
Just leave it blank like this `get()`.

3rd you need to define your variables to be ran after the program closes as outside of the tkinter instance. Then you need to set the global call up in your function.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter
# the 5 below variables are listed outside of tkinter so your while statement
# after the mainloop can use the data.
dt = ""
tg = ""
xz = ""
yz = ""
velz = ""

runwin = tkinter.Tk()
runwin.title("Orbit Sim")
runwin.geometry("320x320")
def run21():
    # this global is needed to tell the run21 function the variables are
    # in the global namespace.
    global dt, tg, xz, yz, velz
    dt=ent21.get()
    tg=ent22.get()
    xz=ent23.get()
    yz=ent24.get()
    velz=ent25.get()
    runwin.destroy()
lbl21 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="How long to simulate for?").pack()
ent21 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent21.pack()
lbl22 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="How many seconds pass per check?").pack()
ent22 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent22.pack()
lbl23 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="Starting Positon? Please state X then Y.").pack()
ent23 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent23.pack()
ent24 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent24.pack()
lbl24 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="Starting Velocity").pack()
ent25 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent25.pack()
btn21 = tkinter.Button(runwin, text="Submit", command=run21).pack()
t=0
runwin.mainloop()

print(dt, tg, xz, yz, velz)
# commented out as it is not testable without knowing what "m" is.
# while t < dt:
#     r3, t = m.sqrt((xz*xz)+(yz*yz)), t+tg
```

Comment: Presumably m is `import math as m`.

Comment: @scotty3785 Could be. It was not in their list of imports so I didn't make that connection. I have not done much with the math library.

Comment: Would make sense. math.sqrt would be valid here

Answer (score 0):

Don't define a widget and use the layout manager on the same line if you wish to use the Widget.

i.e DON'T DO THIS

```
ent21 = tkinter.Entry(runwin).pack()
```

DO THIS

```
ent21 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent21.pack()
```

Like so

```
import tkinter
runwin = tkinter.Tk()
runwin.title("Orbit Sim")
runwin.geometry("320x320")
dt = ""
tg = ""
xz = ""
yz = ""
velz = ""
def run21():
    global dt, tg, xz, yz, velz
    dt=ent21.get()
    tg=ent22.get()
    xz=ent23.get()
    yz=ent24.get()
    velz=ent25.get()
    runwin.destroy()
lbl21 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="How long to simulate for?").pack()
ent21 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent21.pack()
lbl22 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="How many seconds pass per check?").pack()
ent22 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent22.pack()
lbl23 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="Starting Positon? Please state X then Y.").pack()
ent23 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent23.pack()
ent24 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent24.pack()
lbl24 = tkinter.Label(runwin, text="Starting Velocity").pack()
ent25 = tkinter.Entry(runwin)
ent25.pack()
btn21 = tkinter.Button(runwin, text="Submit", command=run21).pack()

runwin.mainloop()
```

One of the other commenters is correct too. Any code after `.mainloop` will not run until after the window is closed. Consider doing this inside the `run21` function so it happens when the button is pressed.

I've removed `"1.0"` from your get since the get method of an entry widget doesn't take any arguments.

Also please consider better naming for your variables. Instead of `ent21` consider `entrySimulationTime` or instead of `ent24` consider `entryStartingPosY`. Your code will be much easier to understand that way.

EDIT: Added globals to expand the scope of dt etc.

Comment: Please also point out the fact you removed "1.0" from the get method.

Comment: @dbaker Difficult to diagnose the problem since I can't see what you've changed. The error indicates that dt doesn't exist at that point in execution or isn't in scope. Did you move the `while t < dt` to the `run21` function?

Comment: If you want variables such as `dt` and `tg` to be available outside of the `run21` function, consider making them globals. (Not the best way but it would work)

Comment: Now its saying that get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Dbaker, You need to remove `"1.0"` from all your get() methods

Comment: My answer includes what they need for global variables outside of the instance. I think they are using tkinter to set the variables and then run a script in the background to do something else.

Comment: Thanks all. After all your advice and add int() to the get() its working

Comment: I was editing the question as you were commenting... On here you need to get an answer up quick before someone else gets in. First draft is never perfect. Removed my statement though (I can see why you took it like you did wasn't accusing you of anything)

Comment: I understand writing a rough draft and then updating it as you go. Just be more careful on your wording. I know and you should know that calling something a copy can be taken very badly in the world of coding.